# Anomaly Detection - Correlated Variables

Tags: r, pca, anomaly-detection

I am working on an 'Anomaly' detection assignment in R. My dataset has around 30,000 records of which around 200 are anomalous. It has around 30 columns & all are quantitative. Some of the variables are highly correlated (~0.9). By anomaly I mean some of the records have unusual (high/low) values for some column(s) while some have correlated variables not behaving as expected. The below example will give some idea.

*Suppose vehicle speed & heart rate are highly positively correlated. Usually vehicle speed varies between 40 & 60 while heart rate between 55-70.*

```
time_s  steering    vehicle.speed running.distance heart_rate
0       -0.011734953    40         0.251867414      58
0.01    -0.011734953    50         0.251936555      61
0.02    -0.011734953    60         0.252005577      62
0.03    -0.011734953    60         0.252074778      90
0.04    -0.011734953    40         0.252074778      65
```

Here we have two types of anomalies. 4th record has exceptionally high value for heart_rate while 5th record seems okay if we look individual columns. But as we can see that heart_rate increases with speed, we expected a lower heart rate for 5th record while we have a higher value.

I could identify the column level anomalies using box plots etc but find it hard to identify the second type. Somewhere I read about PCA based anomaly detection but I couldn't find it's implementation in R.

Will you please help me with PCA based anomaly detection in R for this scenario. My google search was throwing mainly time series related stuff which is not something I am looking for.

Note: There is a similar implementation in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning - 'PCA Based Anomaly Detection for Credit Risk' which does the job but I wan't to know the logic behind it & replicate the same in R.

Comment: This sounds like a case of identifying outliers. If you have a list of column pairs that should be correlated then you could just do `resid(lm(col1 ~ col2, data))` and pick the largest absolute values.

Comment: I've voted to move this over to stats.stackexchange.com, as I think you will get better help there.